# Está correto utilizar redirect route no laravel para fazer a mudança no uri da pagina?

Tags: php, laravel

**No caso ao fazer login com return view, ele carrega a view home encima da url /login:**

```
public function logon(Request $request){
        $dados = $request->all();
        $usuario = Usuario::where('email', $dados['email'])->first();

        if(Auth::check() || ($usuario && Hash::check($dados['senha'], $usuario->senha))){
            Auth::login($usuario, true);
            return view('welcome');
        }else{
            return view('login');
        }
    }
```

**A pergunta é se é uma pratica comum e válida utilizar o redirect, para que ao realizar login ele altere a uri para / novamente:**

```
public function logon(Request $request){
        $dados = $request->all();
        $usuario = Usuario::where('email', $dados['email'])->first();

        if(Auth::check() || ($usuario && Hash::check($dados['senha'], $usuario->senha))){
            Auth::login($usuario, true);
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
```

**Está correto realizar a execução dessa maneira?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você faz o `return redirect()->route('login')` você está redirecionando a requisição para a rota desejada, o que irá acontecer?
Para a rota `login` há um controller, neste controller o método responsável pela rota irá verificar se o usuário está logado e retornará para o caminho configurado, no laravel, o retorno do login é este:

`return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user()) ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());`

Ou seja, nada mais é do que passar novamente pela regra de autenticação do laravel e caso esteja tudo certo, redireciona a requisição para o `redirectPath` configurado na sua aplicação e que tem o valor default a home.

Resumindo: Não é errado fazer isso, apenas tome cuidado pois quando você redireciona uma requisição para outra rota, esta outra rota executará o código do método designado a ela, as vezes você estará gastando processamento atoa.